# How to properly appendChild(a) to a div

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, href

Please help me how to properly fix appendchild(a) in the example below.
I want to add a href with target _blank in the front of the div.

This is my javascript:

```
  onSelection: function (feedback) {
    document.querySelector("#autoComplete").blur();
    const selection = feedback.selection.value.link;

    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute("href", selection);
    a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    PLEASE-HELP-ME-HOW-TO.appendChild(a);
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div data-id="2" class="autoComplete_result">google</div>
```

I need this in my HTML:

```
<a href=https://google.com" target="_blank">
 <div data-id="2" class="autoComplete_result">google</div>
</a>
```

Thank you!

Comment: `a` tags are not valid children under an ol or ul

Comment: I have changed the li to a div

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
var wrapper = document.createElement('a');
wrapper.href="https://www.google.com";
wrapper.target="_blank";


var li= document.querySelector('.autoComplete_result'); 
wrapper.appendChild(li.cloneNode(true)); 
li.parentNode.replaceChild(wrapper, li);

console.log(wrapper.innerHTML)
```

```html
<div data-id="2" class="autoComplete_result">google</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, this is invalid syntax. What you want is:

```
 <li data-id="2" class="autoComplete_result"><a href=https://google.com" target="_blank">google</a></li>
```

Comment: I have changed it to a div instead of li

Comment: still invalid html because an `a` tag can't have `a` div tag as a child.